# django multitable inheritance in django modeladmin

Tags: python, django, orm, django-modeladmin

I have to models

```
class Parent(object):
     text_field = models.TextField()  
     boolean_field = models.BooleanField()

class Child(Parent):
     another_text_field = models.TextField()
```

With the following ModelAdmin

```
class ChildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):                         
    pass 


admin.site.register(Child, ChildAdmin)
```

I currently see all fields in the admin page, i.e. text_field, boolean_field, and another_text_field.

**Question**: How can I get a parent select field and exclude text_field and boolean_field (for latter I guess I can use `exclude`).

**Current Solution**: I add a Form and use its `clean` method to set the parent field. `text_field` and `boolean_field` can be excluded by addind it to the ModelAdmin's `excluded` variable.

Answer (score 0):

simply overwrite fields

```
class Child(Parent):
    another_text_field = models.TextField()
    text_field = None
    boolean_field = None
```

if you want to use inheritance in django models use [abstract](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) models please.

Comment: Thanks @katoozi, but then I'm still missing the `parent` field, for example a model select field.

Comment: can you specify more about your question and what do you wan to do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is really necessary to use model inheritance. if not, you may consider using `OneToOneField` without model inheritance.

Example using `OneToOneField`:

models.py

```py
class Parent(models.Model):
    text_field = models.TextField()  
    boolean_field = models.BooleanField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True)
    child_field = models.TextField()
```

admin.py

```py
@admin.register(Parent)
class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

doing so you can see a drop down menu for picking `Parent` instance at child admin page. but meanwhile, you lose one 'benefit' of using inheritance, which is the availability of `Parent` field in `Child`

as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance),

> All of the fields of Place will also be available in Restaurant,
> although the data will reside in a different database table.

but there is a easy fix for that, just use something like `Child.objects.filter(parent__text_field="something")`. Query performance should be the same (I guess) since implementation in db are basically the same for these two approaches (both use separated table) (please correct if I am wrong)

Apart from from this and admin display behavior, I am not sure how these two approaches (your approach and this answer) are differed.